# "this app tries to attack other mobile and computer systems" warning shown to users

Tags: google-play

I have developed an app for Android and it's not available on Google Play (client doesn't want that). Nevertheless, Play protect started showing a warning for the users (in the title).

I have checked the libraries multiple times and already sent an email, but received no response. I'd appreciate any help regarding this issue, because the app is basically a local news app (political) and it has nothing related to any virus or any exploitation.

The following is the list of used dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.ashokvarma.android:bottom-navigation-bar:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:2.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:1.0.3'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0'
    //3.12.0
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:2.0.0@aar'
    //Optional: see how to use the utility.
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:2.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    implementation 'com.github.KhunHtetzNaing:xGetter:1.9.7'
    implementation 'saschpe.android:customtabs:2.0.0'
    // Butter knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    // YoYo animations
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.huzhenjie:RichTextEditor:1.0.4'
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    implementation project(':libs:searchview')
    implementation project(':libs:AndroidImageSlider')
    implementation project(':libs:MaterialShowcaseView')
}
```

Comment: You can file a Play Protect appeal. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2992033?hl=en. Also, have look at the warning string here https://developers.google.com/android/play-protect/warning-strings, it shows this message when it detects Denial of Service (DoS).

Comment: is your app bundle is signed app bundle
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: I've submitted an appeal, but never received a response from them. My app isn't a signed app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

This library killed my 5 Accounts GG Play. SAD

Comment: What exact library?

Comment: @Jaeger implementation 'com.github.KhunHtetzNaing:xGetter:1.9.7'

Comment: Oh damn. I know why now. Thank you!